# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I have to show that$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{6}.$$ I have now this rewriting:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2-n^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}-n^2\left(\sin\left(\frac1n\right)n-1\right).$$
Maple says it is $1/6.$ But how can I show it formally?

Comment: This comes out of the Maclaurin series for sine.

Comment: Is L'Hospital allowed ?

Answer (score 3):

**By elementary means:**

If existence of a limit $L$ is granted,
$$n^3\left(\frac1n-\sin\frac3{3n}\right)=\frac{(3n)^3}{27}\left(\frac3{3n}-3\sin\frac1{3n}+4\sin^3\frac1{3n}\right),$$ 
and 
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^3\left(\frac1n-\sin\frac3{3n}\right)=\lim_{n/3\to\infty}\frac{n^3}{27}\left(\frac3{n}-3\sin\frac1{n}+4\sin^3\frac1{n}\right)=\frac L9+\frac4{27}$$ giving $$L=\frac16.$$

---

Existence can be proven by

$$x-\frac{x^3}6\le\sin x\le x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}$$

which is easy to establish by five integrations of

$$0<\sin x<1,$$ but this is not elementary and completely solves the question by squeezing.

Comment: Amazing and elegant solution !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: hi Claude. Maybe by smartly combining with the limit $n\sin\frac1n\to1$ we can obtain a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sin\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac1n-\frac1{6n^3}+\frac1{120n^5}+g(n)$$ where $n^3g(n)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to evaluate this limit if we replace n by $\frac{1}{t}$ and then this limit converts to:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}{\frac{t-sint}{t^3}}$$ which simplifies on using taylor series to 
$$\lim_{t\to 0}{\frac{t-(t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}-\frac{t^7}{7!}+....)}{t^3}}$$ which on cancellation and furthur simplification yeilds us $$\lim_{t\to 0}{\frac{\frac{t^3}{3!}-\frac{t^5}{5!}+...}{t^3}}$$ which gives us $$\lim_{t\to 0}{\frac{t-sint}{t^3}}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hospital,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{6x}$$ which is a stronger result.

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1!}-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3}{3!}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^5}{5!}+\dots\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(\frac{1}{6n^3}-\frac{1}{120n^5}+\dots\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{120n^2}+\dots\right)$$
$$=\frac16$$